# Can I use AWS lambda to compress image uploaded to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a social network website where user can upload picture to their post. I know with lambda I can resize image, but can lambda compress/optimize (lossy/lossless) image as well? This way my instance doesn't need to do processing work. If it's not possible, is there alternative where I can optimized image stored in S3 buckets?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this would be a very typical use of Lambda.

I would setup an S3 bucket/location where the uncompressed images get uploaded and setup an s3 bucket notification event that automatically fires each time an image gets dropped into the bucket. IN response to that event a lambda function could be called to perform the compression and/or resizing.

Here is a sample lambda function that may or may not do exactly what you want, but is probably a good starting point: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-image

and here is some documenation on the s3 event notifications: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides resizing images to specific sizes when they are uploaded, also you can apply this solution to resize them on the fly:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/